# virtual machine on kvm hosted on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, kvm, ethernet

I want to create a virtual machine one ubuntu (kvm hypervisor) and I want to dedicate three out of four physical network interfaces to the virtual machine, is it possible ? Can someone explain it to me how I can do it ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A short question that need a very long answer. The very short answer : yes, it is possible.

For the long answer, you'll find good tutorials "[how to forge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorials/kvm/)" that. While they are somehow a little bit outdated, they are still usable and some are very well explained (specially those from Falko Timme). I can advise first reading and understanding https://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-a-debian-squeeze-server and https://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-12.10 .

If you want to use three NIC, just bridge them on the physical machine, and used them bridged from the virtual machines :
On the physical machine (the host), edit /etc/network/interfaces to reflect something like (adapt for your network !) :

```
# The first network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

# The first bridge
auto br1
iface br1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.250
       bridge_ports eno1
       bridge_stp off
       bridge_fd 0
       bridge_maxwait 5
```

The 2nd and 3rd NIC as the first... but differently (is it the same network ?..., I guess...) ! If you prefer (I don't agree), use DHCP, but keep bridge directives.

Then use the three bridged NIC as in :

```
<interface type="bridge">
  <mac address="52:54:00:ab:cd:ef"/>
  <source bridge="br1"/>
  <target dev="vnet8"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

You can achieve that with a creation directive like :

```
virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n vm10 -r 512 --vcpus=2 --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm10.img,size=12 -c /var/lib/libvirt/images/debian-6.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso --vnc --noautoconsole --os-type linux --os-variant debiansqueeze --accelerate --network=bridge:br1 --hvm
```

Pay attention to the `--network=bridge:br1` argument.

Using `virt-manager` will help you a lot auto-configuring all that for you.